# How to return multiple arrays from a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

I've changed the question, the problem I'm facing is with return, I can't seem to return name and phone from addcontact method to main properly.

I need to return the name and phone to main method and update if necessary. The object[] seemed like a good option but I can't seem to make it work properly.

```java
package asstask3;

import java.util.*;

public class AssignmentTask3
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

    public Object[] addcontact(String[] name, String[] phone, int count)
    {
        if ( count == 30 )
        {
            System.out.println( "No more contacts can be added" );
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println( "Enter the name:" );
            name[ count ] = input.next();

            System.out.println( "Enter the phone:" );
            phone[ count ] = input.next();
            count++;
        }
        return new Object[]{name, phone};
    }

    public boolean updatecontact(String[] name, String[] phone, String upname, int count)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        {
            if ( name[ i ].equals( upname ) )
            {
                System.out.println( "Enter to update phone:" );
                phone[ i ] = input.next();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void displaymenu()
    {
        System.out.println( "1. Add New Contact" );
        System.out.println( "2. Update Existing Contact" );
        System.out.println( "0. Exit" );
    }

    public static void main(String []args)throws Exception
    {
        AssignmentTask3 Astask = new AssignmentTask3();
        String name[] = new String[ 30 ];
        String phone[] = new String[ 30 ];

        int count = 1;

        do
        {
            Astask.displaymenu();
            int x = input.nextInt();
            if ( x == 1 )
            {
                Object[] add = Astask.addcontact( name, phone, count );
                String ss = add[1].toString();

                System.out.println( "Name" +name + "Phone"+ phone + "Con" + ss );

            }
            if ( x == 2 )
            {
                System.out.println( "Enter name to update:" );
                String upname = input.next();
                Astask.updatecontact( name, phone, upname, count );
            }
            if ( x == 0 )
            {
                System.exit( 0 );
            }
        } while ( true );

    }
}
```

Name[Ljava.lang.String;@5010be6Phone[Ljava.lang.String;@685f4c2eCon[Ljava.lang.String;@5010be6

this is what I get from print statement after addcontact method is executed.

Comment: Why does the methods have to be static?

Comment: I actually have no clue. this is my first time programming and everything I've done is through IDE recommending me stuff. I'd appreciate if you point out my mistakes

Comment: Well you need to have a plan to complete your assignment.

Comment: Don't make every method static otherwise you miss the point of OOP. Treat static similar to constant. Something that is common across all objects. Lets say you are making a class on shapes. Length, diameter, width etc... will vary for for each shape but `PI` won't. So you can make PI static.

Comment: For object oriented programs, you put the data within objects, and methods provide an interface to that data to the outside code. In this case, you're always passing name, phone, and count to addcontact() and updatecontact(), instead those should be in a class with addContact() and updateContact() methods.

Comment: I notice you're returning an Object[] array with name, phone, and count from addcontact(), so I think you're trying to think of it as an object. That's kind of a dynamic language (like Python) way of doing it, but Java works best when you define the classes separately to make a static declaration of the data structures you want to use.

Comment: do not blindly follow IDE recommendations - it has no idea of what you want to do